# Beamer embedded video+adobe reader XI

Tags: beamer, embedding, multimedia, video

I struggle on a video embedding problem using beamer and I can't seem to find any reasonable explanation to my issues.

I am doing a beamer presentation that includes a video, here's my MWE :

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test frame}
\movie[width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.263\textwidth,poster]{}{images/test.avi}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Compiles perfectly fine but when opened in Reader XI on Windows 7, the pdf shows a blank rectangle and clicking has no effect.

- Weird thing #1 : if I move `test.avi` away from my `images` folder and run the pdf again, Reader says it couldn't find the file and asks me to manually retrieve it. When I do and select the file from the Reader dialog box (same file in a different folder) it works just fine : I have the poster and the video running correctly in the pdf.
- Weird thing #2 : if I move my entire work folder to my external hard drive (did it originally to test it on a colleagues computer) and run the very same pdf that has just been copied there, everything works perfectly.

It makes no sense to me that the very same pdf file displays properly when run from an external storage and won't when run from my C:. Would you have any idea why I cannot get the expected behavior from simply compiling and running the pdf locally with Reader XI ? That seems to a Reader problem more than a LaTeX one as the LaTeX part if fine but maybe you would have insight on why these surprising and painful things are going on and what Beamer could have to do with it.

Thank you very much !

Comment: It seems that the folder inside the usb is better defined that the folder in the c drive. Such things can be solved with ways like `\graphicspath{{./images/}}` that most times work for every OS.

Comment: Can you try with `./images/test.avi`?

Comment: also there is a `}` missing after `\begin{frame`

Comment: Hi @koleygr, I found it is indeed path related; Breaking it down, I noticed that the video doesn't embed properly when there is a period `.` in the path. My lab setup being `C:/Users/firstname.lastname/`

I can bypass the problem by putting the folder in a path that has no `.` but would you know of anyway to make video embedding path independent ?